# mousedown div containment to parent(latest)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My inner div is suppose to move around with the mouse cursor on mousemove but i want it to stop at the if statement if it is dragging with the isDragging variable so it will drag smoothly but it seems to not stop any suggestion and help would be appreciated
update: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPn3v/47/)

```
var yellow = $('#yellow');
var offset = yellow.offset();
var offsetWidth = offset.left + yellow.width();
var offsetHeight = offset.top + yellow.height();
var isDragging = false;

var red = $('#red');

$('#red').hide();

yellow.on('mousedown', function(event) {    
    $('#red').show();  
});
yellow.on('mouseup', function(event) {
    $('#red').hide();        
});
yellow.on('mousemove', function (e) {

    if(e.pageX > offset.left + ($(red).width() / 2) && e.pageX < offsetWidth - ($(red).width() / 2)
        && e.pageY > offset.top + ($(red).height() / 2) && e.pageY < offsetHeight - ($(red).height() / 2) && !isDragging ){
        red.css("left", e.pageX - $(red).width() / 2 );
        red.css("top", e.pageY - $(red).height() / 2);
    }

    $('#red').draggable(
        {'containment':'#yellow',
         start:function(event, ui) {
            isDragging = true;
        },
        drag:function(event, ui) {
            isDragging = true;
        },stop:function(event, ui) {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    });
});


<div id="yellow">
    <div id="red"></div>
</div>

    #yellow {
position: absolute;    
width: 250px; 
height: 250px; 
background-color: Yellow; 
}

#red {
position: absolute;
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
background-color: red; 
z-index: 100; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried just adding draggable on mousedown but it only fires on drag so that containment would work. But i don't know if you can fire drag on mousedown i think you have to start drag first

Comment: more like - what code have you done - in order to help you with that. What you're essentially asking is for an entirety of code - which you could google for and get someone's class.

Comment: I can position the child div in ther center on mousedown with event.pageX and event.pageY coords but i can't do the boundaries of the parent div

Comment: Please don't be ashamed of your code that you insist on not sharing with us.

Comment: added some code but don't know how to do the boundaries

Answer (score 0):

I can't say i am proud of this solution but it seems to get the stuff done:

http://jsfiddle.net/pPn3v/42/

```
var yellow = $('#yellow');
var offset = yellow.offset();
var offsetWidth = offset.left + yellow.width();
var offsetHeight = offset.top + yellow.height();

var red = $('#red');

yellow.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if(e.pageX+red.width() < offsetWidth
      && e.pageY+red.height() < offsetHeight){
        red.css("left", e.pageX);
        red.css("top", e.pageY);
    }
});

red.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if(e.pageX+red.width() < offsetWidth
      && e.pageY+red.height() < offsetHeight){
        red.css("left", e.pageX);
        red.css("top", e.pageY);  
    }               
});
```

Comment: I updated you're example of what you did and changed the div elements so they are nested and added jquery-ui library and added draggable({}); to the example it still needs some tweaking. What can you do from there http://jsfiddle.net/pPn3v/43/

Comment: but its not quite perfect tho